# Target class [Spatie\Permission\Middleware\PermissionMiddleware] does not exist

Tags: permissions, blogs, laravel-10, laravel-middleware

How to fix Target class [Spatie\Permission\Middleware\PermissionMiddleware] does not exist.

I hope the code can run smoothly again, please help me, I've tried changing the code but it still doesn't work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf5dZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Middleware folder name in spatie vendor folder.

**Folder path** => vendor -> spatie-> laravel-permission -> src -> Middleware/Middlewares

Then in **Kernal.php** change the Middleware folder name accordingly

protected $routeMiddleware = [
....
'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware::class,
'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
]